# How to find out particular word in a string

Tags: c++

Problem : I am getting Problem while pass string and find out word in that string.

I have tried below code:

```
if(string.find("Z03"))
{
   // field exists
   return true;
}
```

String :Z030000000057

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
if(string.find("Z03"))
{
   // field exists
   return true;
}
```

when i pass string in message like ";Z030000000057" then its enter in the loop but when i simply pass "Z030000000057" its go into loop.

Kindly help me for this.

Comment: Read [some docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: find does not return a boolean, its returns the index of where the string was found. You're implicitly converting an int to bool. [see documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Answer (score 2):

`find()` returns the index of the first occurrence, or `string::npos`. Your `if` is testing if `find()` returned zero (i.e. first occurrence at beginning of string) or not (i.e. search string occurs later, or not at all).

You are *probably* looking for...

```
if ( string.find( "Z03" ) != std::string::npos )
{
    // field exists
    return true;
}
```

...which *perhaps* could be shortened to...

```
return ( string.find( "Z03" ) != std::string::npos );
```

...if neither the true nor the false branch do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation on the 'find' method: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

The method returns position of the first character of the found substring or     std::string::npos if the substring is not found.

Regarding your examples:

```
std::string s("Z030000000057");
if(s.find("Z03"))
{
   // execution DOES NOT goes here because find returns 0 as found position
}

s = ";Z030000000057";
if(s.find("Z03"))
{
    // execution goes here because find returns 1 as found position
}
```

The correct code would be:

```
if (s.find("Z03") != std::string::npos)
{
    // field exists
}
```

I recommend using cppreference for further checking standard functions, it's very useful.